# ng-bind-html in a svg text tag do not display tspan in firefox and IE

Tags: angularjs, svg, ng-bind-html, tspan

I can't succeed in build an svg with angularjs when tspan are load from ng-bind-html attribute, Firefox and IE do not display them.

My controler look like that :

```
$scope.titlenotok="svg not ok";
var content = '<tspan dy="20" x="0"  xml:space="preserve">line1 not ok</tspan><tspan dy="30" x="0"  xml:space="preserve">line 2 not ok</tspan>'
$scope.notok = $sce.trustAsHtml(content);
```

I create a fiddle to illustrate

http://jsfiddle.net/3WNhT/

For chrome it's OK.

Comment: Because the tspan is created as an unknown tspan element in the html namespace rather than a real tspan in the SVG namespace. You'd need to use DOMParser instead and make sure the tspan has an SVG xmlns attribute.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I will try to create a directive and use createElementNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert was right.

Here is my solution.
The secret was to use createElementNS. so that, The browser understand that it is a svg element and not a html element.

Here is the directive

```
app.directive('multilinesvgtext',  function () {
    var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var myLink = function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        attrs.$observe('contenu', function (val) {
            var data = val;

            var generateTSpan = function (lineOftext) {
                var tspanElement = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'tspan');
                tspanElement.setAttribute('x', attrs.x);
                tspanElement.setAttribute('dy', attrs.dy);
                tspanElement.setAttribute('class', attrs.class);
                tspanElement.setAttribute('xml:space', 'preserve');
                var tspanContent = document.createTextNode(lineOftext);
                tspanElement.appendChild(tspanContent);
                return tspanElement;
            };
            // We delete the old children
            while (elem[0].firstChild) {
                elem[0].removeChild(elem[0].firstChild);
            }
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            for(var i= 0; i < lines.length; i++)
            {
                var textContent = lines[i]!=='' ? lines[i] : ' ';
                var newTspanElement = generateTSpan(textContent);
                elem[0].appendChild(newTspanElement);
            }
        });
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: myLink
    };
 }
);
```

Which can be uses like that :

```
<text multilinesvgtext  x="30" y="168" fill="#FFFFFF" data-dy="13" class="myclass" data-contenu="{{mydata}}"></text>
```

My directive add tspan children for each line of text in mydata and use data-dy attribute as dy attribute for this tspan.

Comment: With this solution, there is a last problem : The xml:space attribute is not taken into account by the browser.

Comment: The solution was   tspanElement.setAttributeNS( 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace' , 'xml:space' , 'preserve');